# Way to know number of unread message from a particular number

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am getting number of  unread message in inbox by the following code .

```
public int getMessageCountUnread(){
        resolver = getContentResolver() ; 
        Cursor c = resolver.query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 0", null, null);
        int unreadMessagesCount = c.getCount();
        c.deactivate();
        return unreadMessagesCount;
    }
```

Now I want to know the number of unread sms from a particular number. How can I know the number of unread SMS from a particular number?

How can I set the query ?
WHAT to do if I want to know no of read messages from a particular number ?

Comment: can you please explain query..??

Comment: I want to find the no of unread message from a particular number .

Comment: Do you have permission to read SMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use columns from `android.provider.Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns` in your ContentResolver query to find SMS messages that are from a specific address and not read:

Use these column contants:

```
Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.ADDRESS
Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.READ
```

Something like this:

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.READ + " = ? and "
                + Telephony.TextBaseSmsColumns.ADDRESS + "= ?"   ,
                new String[]{"false", "+1 123 123 1234"},
                Telephony.Sms.Conversations.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
int unreadCount = cursor.getCount();
```

And to know no of read messages from a particular number, just a minor change:

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.READ + " = ? and "
                    + Telephony.TextBaseSmsColumns.ADDRESS + "= ?"   ,
                    new String[]{"true", "+1 123 123 1234"},
                    Telephony.Sms.Conversations.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

**Update:**

If above code doesn't work, use this:

```
String address = 0123456789;
Cursor unreadcountcursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), 
new String[]{}, "read = 0 and address='"+address+"'", null, null); 
int count = unreadcountcursor.getCount();
```

Comment: what does the log says?

Comment: near "Where" syntax error (code 1) : while compiling : select * from sms where (where read = ? and address = ? ) order by data desc

Comment: is there any solution ? Why do my app crash ?

Comment: There is syntax error in query. Remove "WHERE " part from it and then try.

Comment: Does  this code give no of unread sms from a particular number ?

Comment: WHAT to do if I want to know no of read messages from a particular number ?

Comment: just change "false" to "true" thats it

Comment: It doesnot correctly shows the number of unread messages . What can I do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89568/discussion-between-shahzeb-and-osimer-pothe).